# how Bootstrap framework identifies the browser and device width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web development, and this is my assignment of developing our lab's website.Bootstrap framework says they support various 11 frameworks. How does it identify whether it is chrome or IE or opera? and how does it identify the device width? I think some function must be written in javascript to identify it, so i was trying to understand bootstrap.min.js. But unable to find such function.
Can you please help me, help will be appreciated

Comment: You want to go through media screen css styles first

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp --- Unless you have a more specific question, just read up on `@media` queries.

Comment: Thank You so much for your comments. But as media queries also support some advanced versions of browsers, so how does it actually identifies which browser you are using and whats the version of that browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Its just simple Media Queries. Its very simple concept. Go through this CHRIS COYIER's [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) to find how it work, again it very simple.

Here is simple example of the mediaquery

```
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
```

This code says at screen size from 600px to 800px the html background color should be red;

Comment: Thank You so much for the help.

Comment: But media queries help to identify the screen width, then how internaly it has implemented that function and also how does it actually identifies the bowser ?

Comment: you dont have to worry about how the code is going to identify which browser it is. Bootstrap handles that, automatically. Browser related codes are termed as Cross Browser Codes, to understand this in details google for "The Principles Of Cross-Browser CSS Coding by Smashing Magazine" this will help you.